# 2014 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/900/2014-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

Here's how it'll work:

- During the nomination phase, (so, until March 10th at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 3:00 pm EST on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at current.
- At the end of the phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. That said, if I have concerns about any questions in this fashion, I will be sure to point this out in comments before the decision making time.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this new process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Comment: Now I'm tempted to nominate just to answer the questions :)

Answer (score 4):

I am going to be adding some questions that I think are relevant from the [2014 SO Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221594/2014-so-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).

> How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 3):

> What's your take on [link-only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) that get flagged for not being answers? Should they be removed when flagged, or are they worth keeping around if they answer the question?

<sub>meta.bicycles related- [Avoiding 'Just Buy A New One' or 'Here's A Link' Answers](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28/avoiding-just-buy-a-new-one-or-heres-a-link-answers)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

> a) What is, in your opinion as a potential future moderator, the biggest problem that bicycles.SE currently faces? b) If you were to get elected, what actions would you take towards resolving these issues?

Answer (score 2):

Do you think bicycles has too many unanswered questions? Why not? If so, what would you do about it?